# Triaging specific causes of bulk query retries

Tags: timeout, bulk-api-v2

I'm working on implementing a record download process using SF's Bulk API 2.0 Query support. I have some jobs that take many hours (more than some other comparable jobs) for the query to transition to `JobComplete`, and the cause seems to be a high retry count (over 100) in the job information. Other jobs with similar numbers of records and columns (in other objects) still take a while, but incur no retries. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/bulk_api_2_0_troubleshoot_query_timeouts.htm) on timeouts notes that I should apply additional filter criteria. But it's unclear what I should be filtering on, or if that's even my problem. Technically I'm not hitting timeouts, just incredibly long wait times for jobs to complete.

The query is just a straight field selection from a single table with a `SystemModstamp` clause, like so:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d... FROM Contact WHERE SystemModstamp < 2023-05-03T21:24:23.652472Z
```

The fields selected are a mix of custom and built-in fields.

Some additional observations:

- I'm running a `queryAll` query, because I do want deleted or merged records.
- If I limit the query to only built-in fields, I can complete a 12 million record query in < 10 minutes.
- The more custom columns I add, the slower the job gets, but it seems to slow down in almost geometric proportion to the number of columns. It seems to be potentially related to locks on specific columns (if column-level locking is even a thing in SF).

I have no control over the data model(s), so I need to find a way to work around any (potential) inefficient data modeling by modifying how I query the data.

Is there a way to diagnose the root cause of retries via the API? Are there any known strategies for dealing with excessive retries?

Comment: Filter criteria here means that you need to make your SOQL query selective following the guidelines mentioned in [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385213&type=1) . Instead of `SystemModstamp < 2023-05-03` you can alter it to make it `SystemModstamp < 2023-05-03 and SystemModstamp > 2023-04-03`

Comment: One thing I've found is that it seems to be the addition of custom fields that slows it down.  I can run the same query with just standard SF fields and it can complete tens of millions of records in minutes.  Adding a number of custom fields will make it take hours and incur numerous retries.  Are there any particular types of custom fields that might cause this behavior?  My experiments so far have yielded nothing helpful.

Comment: @Swetha That link has a lot of helpful information.  Thank you!